Spam influx: Time to reduce or remove spam flag rate-limiting for community members in good standing?
In recent days, Super User has been hit by a large amount of spam. The spam flag rate-limiting timer is hindering our ability to deal with the spam in a timely manner.  Given the current context, would it be possible to reduce or remove the spam flag rate-limiting timer on a trial basis for community members in good standing to see if it helps resolve this issue?

This was previously proposed and negatively received - most likely because SmokeDetector was down at the time

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Thanks Sonic.  SmokeDetector is up and running now (and for the past few weeks), correct?

In the middle of a strke, its scabbing. Right now? I think we probably have a common purpose.

Also I'd add that as an affected site - I'd consider that the total number of flags per day would act as an acceptable rate limit. We're not the only affected site - and its noticeable despite most of the anti spam systems, official, community led, or moderator tools working as they should be.

@JourneymanGeek The goal of my comment was to prevent people from voting to close as a duplicate without context, i.e., if they just see the title and negative score.

@JourneymanGeek I think the author is referring to the 5-second rate limit between flags. I did run into it when flagging spam as part of the current wave.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Yes, exactly. Myself as well.

Removing the rate-limit would certainly aid the Charcoal community in its Autoflagging efforts.

considering I was talking to the author about just that, I'm entirely aware of what the author is talking about. I was pointing out that the circumstances for it being poorly recieved are different from what they are now

Sorry but flagging in less than 5 seconds between each flag means using automated scripts to flag, and I'm against it. Too prone for errors.

@ShadowWizard When there's an influx of similar-looking obvious spam it's easy to manually flag every 3 seconds or so. I've certainly found myself slowed down without scripts being involved.

@ShadowWizard "flagging in less than 5 seconds between each flag means using automated scripts to flag" that's false, I do it manually, it doesn't take 5 seconds to see than an obvious spam is spam, far from it. Don't make others slower because your are slow.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog yep as usual people downvoting without thinking about later ramifications.

Can we just ban phrases found exclusively in spam at the system level?

@CPlus There are very very few phrases only found in spam, if any

@CPlus Also, automated bans fail - both in being too restrictive and not restrictive enough. I think Charcoal's spam checks are pretty much the best we're going to get.

@CPlus If specific phrases are banned, then people will just use other phrases or work-arounds. That's been seen time and time again on the network for many things that are banned. The only way that would actually be effective over time is if SE implemented shadow banning, so that the poster doesn't know that what they posted was blocked. SE has been adamantly against implementing shadow banning since the inception of the site.

@Starship Well there are a few that are found very often and exclusively in the extra-low quality spam waves that have been plaguing SU and other sites.

@Makyen What is they are just given a generic error that does not specify that they were blocked for using a specific phrase?

@CPlus there is a precursor for that behavior with CJK spam, but the CJK case is much simpler that it just blocks all characters, where this spam wave is using specific phrases (meaning: SE needs to be very active in adapting the phrases).
